# High Availability on DAS HPE

Tags: high-availability, failovercluster, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, direct-attached-storage

Anyone who can assist me?

I currently have a DL360 Gen9 HPE server Directly attached to HPE MSA 2040 device (DAS). I now need to ensure HA on the server level, is it possible to have FO cluster (Hyper-V) on this platform without introducing a Fiber Switch (SAN) connection?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You cant build up a failover cluster with just a single server, not to mention an HA at the node level.

Another issue is your storage device that is considered as an obvious SPoF as well.

What you really need for implementing a true HA is one more compute host + one more DAS connected to the second node. You then take something like [Starwind](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san), do shared storage and eventually present it to the failover cluster.

By and large, virtual SAN rocks!

Answer (score -2):

No. It is also not possible WITH introducint a SAN architecture.

Your probem is:

> to HPE MSA 2040 device (DAS)

This is singular, i.e. single point of failure, i.e. not high available.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to configure SAN without loosing the data on the MSA 2040 Device?

Comment: No idea. Care about reading the documentation?